# Bug in hat dash (macOS, safari, spacebar)

Tags: bug, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020, hat-dash, mac

I'm on a macbookpro 13 inches and when trying to play on safari, as soon as a tap my spacebar, the page scroll down and I can't see anything from the game. This appear to be a bug, originally reported [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403820/6044997)

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Comment: Can you make sure that the modal has focus before you start? Any console errors? Try the up arrow instead?